# Stata: refer to categorical fields by their labels instead of their numbers

Tags: stata

I am trying to use categorical variables more efficiently.

Suppose I have a categorical variable `phone`, which has the following values:

```
----------------------
    phone |      Freq.
----------+-----------  
Landline  |        223    
Mobile    |     49,297
     Both |      1,308
```

I want to run a command something like this:

```
sum x if phone == Mobile
```

In order to do this, I need to run the following three commands:

```
// figure out what the label is called
. describe phone, full

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label
-------------------------------------------
phone           byte    %15.0g     phone_label

// list the label so i can figure out what number goes with what category
. label list phone_label

phonel:
           1 Landline
           2 Mobile
           3 Both

// run the command with the numeric category identifier
. sum x if phone == 2
```

And now my code has the obscure line `phone == 2` which will not be clear to another user unless they go through the same steps above.

Is there a way to directly use the categorical identifier "Mobile" instead of the numeric identifier 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can** select observations using value labels.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. count if foreign=="Foreign":origin
  22
```

You need to know the name of the value labels, here `origin`. You can look that up in several ways.

This is documented at [U] 13.11 in Stata 14 and (under possibly different chapter and section numbers) in earlier versions. See also http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0009

Comment: @pnj, you can combine Nick's solution with _extended macro functions_ to automatically fetch the name of the value labels: ``count if foreign=="Foreign":`: value label foreign'``. See `help extended_fcn`, for more.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to directly use the value label (`Mobile`, for example) rather than the value itself? Not that I am aware of.

The underlying data do not change when you define/assign a value label to your categorical data. The value label, in this case, is simply a visual aid to the programmer.

If you wanted to have the exact functionality above, you could consider recoding your variable to have string values, but this doesn't seem the best course:

```
decode phone, gen(phone_str)
summ if phone_str=="Mobile" //OK
```

Another way would be to modify the workflow you use above to avoid the problem with "obscure line `phone==2`". More programmatic might be:

```
label list `: value label phone'       // display label in one step
local mobile_value 2                   // save value of "Mobile"
summ x if phone==`mobile_value'        // clearly show you are cutting over mobiles
```

Comment: The mapping from a numeric variable with value labels to the corresponding string variables does not need a `generate` followed by one or more `replace`. There is a dedicated `decode` command for that.